# Asp.net Web Api as an Api Gateway

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In my organization I have several asp.net web api projects.
I'm willing to develop an web api which will act like a gateway and have single entry point.

I tried handlers and filters but routing doesn't allow me to that.

Let me explain,  what  I really want to do

**Let HumanResourceProject at : api.domain.com/api/hr**

sample controller is api/hr/LeaveRecord/GetByEmployee/ 

**Let CRMProject           at : api.domain.com/api/crm**

sample controller is api/crm/Customers/GetByRegion/ 

**Let Gateway              at : api.domain.com/api/gateway**

I want my gateway to handle requests like
1.  api.domain.com/api/gateway/**api/crm/Customers/GetByRegion/**
        or
    api.domain.com/api/gateway/**api/hr/LeaveRecord/GetByEmployee/**

2. Make some controls like ip/access/browser etc.
3. I want to call correct api controller api/crm/Customers/GetByRegion/
4. Return response of called api's controller.

[image]

Comment: You seem to want to go with the API gateway, but then again, all you seem to want to use it for is routing of requests to the relevant party. If this is the case, then have a look at IIS URL rewrite. If it is hosted in the cloud, then look at Azure Service Bus Relays.

Comment: Also I want to implement some security controls in Gateway.

Comment: @zapoo Have you found a solution?

Comment: Since then, I have APIs that trusts same Identity provider. (i.e identity server4) Authorization and Authentication controls more easy now.
Specifically for this `gateway pattern` I would use nginx for on-premise, on cloud you have many options.

Answer (score 0):

you can use IApplicationBuilder , and inject this is your Configure() method in Startup class in .net core.

so you all request will be processed by Pre-request handler before hitting to the actual controller.

```java
 public static IApplicationBuilder MiddleWare(this IApplicationBuilder
 builder)
         {
             return builder.UseMiddleware<RequestHandler>();
         }
```

here your all request will be handled by RequestHandler first before hitting to the actual controller.

Comment: although 5 years ago .net core was not around, thanks for reminding we have middleware now.

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing in my my organization, created a outbound gateway using [Ocelot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/implement-api-gateways-with-ocelot)

It's very simple. My problem is that we have a legacy windows software and a newer web app version, so we had this problem

[image]

with the gateway implemented we have this now

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although it's been ages this question was asked but I feel my answer shall be beneficial to any developer thinking of an implementation in such scenarios

- API Gateway with Ocelot is the best thing to opt for
- Have all your downstreams API's ('n' number of microservices) configured in ocelot file along with other configurations like Rate Limiting, Cache response etc
- Implement any type of Authorization/Authentication in Middelware of gateway. (JWT token based, CORS, Scope checks etc)
  ***API Gateway*** is really a ***'boon'*** while dealing with microservices.